# How to know if class constructor was called via super?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

If I have this:

```
class Human {
    constructor(){

    }
}

class Person extends Human {
    constructor(){
        super();
    }
}
```

Is it possible to know if the Human's constructor was called via the `Person` class? I thought about `arguments.callee` but that is deprecated.

Comment: Why would you need to know that?

Comment: @FelixKling when you ask I get kind of embarassed :) But I had a sequence of classes extended and needed to set a property in a parent/super class because it was calling a method that needed it. Bad code design. But while I was fixing it the question came to me.

Comment: You really should fix your design so that `Human` does not need to know what is is being subclassed by.  The fact that you think you need to know that means the design is flawed.

Comment: @jfriend00 agree, that is what I did. But before I started fixing it the question came up and I could not answer it or find the answer myself.

Comment: It's not worth answering because you should NEVER do it and people here should NOT recommend doing it.

Comment: @jfriend00 I upvoted your comment here. Agree. Having said that It might be the case its needed to test or patch something. Its against semantics, good sense, etc... but I just want to learn and understand better.

Comment: I don't think you can do this in a way which can't be fooled with `Reflect.construct(Person, [], Human)`

Comment: @FelixKling To implement an “interface,” where a superclass demands its subclasses to have things it wants them to have.

Comment: @jfriend00 And also, to implement a “_protected_ constructor,” where the constructor is only used internally by the class and its subclasses and the user can call static (possibly asynchronous) factory method to create a pre-initialized instance.

Comment: There *are* legitimate reasons to detect this, e.g. if you want to call `Object.seal(this)` at the end of the constructor, but only if that constructor is the final one (since otherwise it would be impossible to extend the class)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's easy (but ill-advised) to check whether the instance is of a particular subclasss:

```
class Human {
    constructor(){
        console.log(this instanceof Person);
    }
}
```

To check whether it's an instance of the base class (and not a subclass) you can use:

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(this) === Human.prototype
```

[ so long as you haven't messed with the class and overwritten the `prototype` object ]

You can also check the value of `this.constructor.name` - it'll reflect the type of the initial constructor called, and doesn't change when the base class constructor is called, although this could fail if the code is minified.

Comment: Good ideas, maybe `this.constructor.name` could be a idea also? http://www.es6fiddle.net/io8yos23/

Comment: @Rikard I wonder perhaps though if that's less "safe", since checking for `Human.prototype` within the `Human` class should guarantee that you're checking the correct object, and not any other class that's perhaps not in scope but has the same name.

Comment: Good point, it would be safe if I used a _Symbol_ as class name, overkill maybe.

Comment: @Rikard this.constructor.name is not compatible with minification.

Comment: This can be fooled with `Reflect.construct(Person, [], Human)`

Comment: This is just BAD object oriented design and should never be recommended.  A superclass should never have to know about a specific sub-class.  If you think it does, then the design needs to be fixed/reworked so that is not the case.  There is always a way to do proper design without a super class knowing about a subclass.  You may need to create virtual methods that a subclass overrides, but the superclass should never be coded with any specific knowledge of subclasses.

Comment: @estus very true, when I Babel and Uglify it [then that check is gone](https://jsfiddle.net/9wq8tm81/). Alnitak thanks! (http://www.es6fiddle.net/io8z64dk/)

Comment: @jfriend00 wrong, since `super` is required within the subclass constructor, in order to use `this`. you may have `constructor --> initialize` in both sub and superclasses, but don't want to go `super constructor --> initialize --> constructor`

Comment: it's functional and compositional, rather than "object-oriented"

Comment: @neaumusic - I have no idea what your first comment has to do with this situation or what it even means.  I stand by my comment that a base class shouldn't be coded to have specific knowledge of individual derived classes.  If it is, then there's very likely a better way to structure the code.

Comment: @jfriend00 sometimes you have shared functionality that you don't want to smash together, and sometimes you do write base classes to be extended upon

Comment: the base component can both be functional and a 'library', but it's a matter of diving down into the superclass, needing to come up in order to override params before initializing

Comment: @neaumusic - It's normal and desirable to design base classes to be subclassed and have things in their implementation overriden.  That's a classic OO design pattern.  But, it's not considered good design to have `if` statements in a base class that modify their behavior based on which subclass it is. That is the wrong way to implement sub-class-specific behavior.  Better to create a method, have the base class call it and let the subclass override it to implement their specific behavior.  In C++, these would be  declared as virtual methods.  In Javascript, all methods are essentially virtual.

Comment: @jfriend00 interesting, thanks for the reply. I would consider it functional or compositional, rather than object oriented, because there's well defined pathing, and the main resource-sharing comes from the constructor

Comment: @neaumusic - Compositional and functional programming are fine techniques for appropriate circumstances, but they are not the inheritance pattern that I've been objecting to.

Comment: NodeJS giving me `TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function` when I try to import a subclass into a parent class for the purposes of the above

Answer (score 3):

Use [`new.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new.target) if you can use [es6 syntax](https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_operators_new_target):

```js
function calledBy(cls, target){
    if(!target) throw new Error("called without new"); // unnecessary when in strictmode
    if(target!==cls) console.log("Called using super() by subclass");
    else console.log("Called directly with new");
}

class A {
    constructor(){
        calledBy(A, new.target)
    }
}

class B extends A {}

new A() // "Called directly with new"
new B() // "Called using super() by subclass"
```